# Cannot disable rails assets pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a rails '4.2.11.1' application. I want to dissable assets compilation, minifying, pipeline in development. in order to use [indium debugger](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/Indium/issues/173)

The rails app seems to be set up with sprokets. so in my config/application.rb I changed to this:

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

also in config/environmetns/development.rb I have this setup:

```
  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
```

but nothing happens and I get the files:
assets/stixs.self-7246a54effa0c5edaa806b9c4fbc6ba4617c0d80bef8c236f9a4cbcfcf7f0be7.js

finally I get this files not minifyed, or compresed but how can I get that rails work with serving the files in app/assets/javascripts in de delopment environment

Answer (score 0):

Technique Sprockets uses for fingerprinting is to insert a hash of the content into the name

Add this in your development.rb

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

I hope that work for you.